# VueJS routing not displaying components

Tags: vue-router

For an unknown reason, VueJS router only displays the root component (Home), and does not display any other components. Console does not indicate any errors, and I also do not see any error in my code.

```
    main.js:
    
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
    import App from './App.vue'
    import { routes } from './routes';
    
    Vue.use(VueRouter);
    
    const router = new VueRouter({
      routes
    });
    
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      render: h => h(App)
    })
    
    
    routes.js:
    
    import User from './components/user/User.vue';
    import Detail from './components/user/UserDetail.vue';
    import Home from './components/Home.vue';
    
    export const routes = [
        { path: '', component: Home },
        { path: './user', component: User },
        { path: './detail', component: Detail }
    ];
    
    
    Home.vue:
    
    
    <template>
        <div>
            <h1>The Home Page</h1>
            <hr>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab asperiores, aut autem, blanditiis consequuntur
                dolore excepturi laborum maiores minima nihil non nulla obcaecati quas quibusdam quod sed suscipit vero
                voluptatem.</p>
    
        </div>
    </template>
    
    
    User.vue:
    
    
    <template>
        <div>
            <h1>The User Page</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos incidunt corporis officiis hic aliquid voluptatem aspernatur? Odio non cum sint deleniti veritatis maxime, nihil officia dolore odit numquam harum voluptates.</p>
        </div>
    </template>
        
       
    UserDetail.vue:
    
    
       

 <template>
        <h3>Some User Details</h3>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
        created() {
            console.log('we are on details page');
        }
    }
    </script>
    
    
    
    App.vue:
    
    
    
    <template>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <h1>Routing</h1>
                    <hr>
                    <router-view/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
        export default {
        }
    </script>
    
    <style>
    </style>
```

User.vue also contains a console.log, but console remains silent, it does not run.

The components are in the linked directory: user, within components, the path is indeed correct.

Home is displayed perfectly, but no other components show up. So what the heck is going on?

Comment: UserDetail.vue contains the console.log, not User.vue, but it does not really matter.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the bug : in the routes.js file there are dots '.' before the paths! That was it.